# Why I can't reach HandleAuthenticateAsync in my custom JwtBearerHandler without producing an exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-authorization

I'm trying to implement a custom JWTBearerHandler for authorizing some requests in my API, due to I need to inject a custom token validator I've made.

So, I did implement **AuthenticationHandler** based on the implementation of [**JwtBearerHandler**](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/87a92e52c8b4bb7cb75ff78d53d641b1d34f8775/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs):

```cs
public class CustomHandler: AuthenticationHandler<JwtBearerOptions>
    {
        private OpenIdConnectConfiguration _configuration;

        public CustomHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock) 
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// The handler calls methods on the events which give the application control at certain points where processing is occurring. 
        /// If it is not provided a default instance is supplied which does nothing when the methods are called.
        /// </summary>
        protected new JwtBearerEvents Events
        {
            get => (JwtBearerEvents)base.Events; 
            set => base.Events = value; 
        }

        protected override Task<object> CreateEventsAsync()
            => Task.FromResult<object>(new JwtBearerEvents());

        /// <summary>
        /// Searches the 'Authorization' header for a 'Bearer' token. If the 'Bearer' token is found, it is validated using <see cref="TokenValidationParameters"/> set in the options.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            string token = null;
            try
            {
                // Give application opportunity to find from a different location, adjust, or reject token
                var messageReceivedContext = new MessageReceivedContext(Context, Scheme, Options);

                // event can set the token
                await Events.MessageReceived(messageReceivedContext);
                if (messageReceivedContext.Result != null)
                {
                    return messageReceivedContext.Result;
                }

                // If application retrieved token from somewhere else, use that.
                token = messageReceivedContext.Token;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    string authorization = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];

                    // If no authorization header found, nothing to process further
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization))
                    {
                        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
                    }

                    if (authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        token = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                    }

                    // If no token found, no further work possible
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                    {
                        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
                    }
                }

                if (_configuration == null && Options.ConfigurationManager != null)
                {
                    _configuration = await Options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(Context.RequestAborted);
                }

                var validationParameters = Options.TokenValidationParameters.Clone();
                if (_configuration != null)
                {
                    var issuers = new[] { _configuration.Issuer };
                    validationParameters.ValidIssuers = validationParameters.ValidIssuers?.Concat(issuers) ?? issuers;

                    validationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys = validationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys?.Concat(_configuration.SigningKeys)
                        ?? _configuration.SigningKeys;
                }

                List<Exception> validationFailures = null;
                SecurityToken validatedToken;
                foreach (var validator in Options.SecurityTokenValidators)
                {
                    if (validator.CanReadToken(token))
                    {
                        ClaimsPrincipal principal;
                        try
                        {
                            principal = validator.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            // TODO: Log
                            // Logger.TokenValidationFailed(ex);

                            // Refresh the configuration for exceptions that may be caused by key rollovers. The user can also request a refresh in the event.
                            if (Options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound && Options.ConfigurationManager != null
                                && ex is SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException)
                            {
                                Options.ConfigurationManager.RequestRefresh();
                            }

                            if (validationFailures == null)
                            {
                                validationFailures = new List<Exception>(1);
                            }
                            validationFailures.Add(ex);
                            continue;
                        }

                        // TODO: Same here
                        // Logger.TokenValidationSucceeded();

                        var tokenValidatedContext = new TokenValidatedContext(Context, Scheme, Options)
                        {
                            Principal = principal,
                            SecurityToken = validatedToken
                        };

                        await Events.TokenValidated(tokenValidatedContext);
                        if (tokenValidatedContext.Result != null)
                        {
                            return tokenValidatedContext.Result;
                        }

                        if (Options.SaveToken)
                        {
                            tokenValidatedContext.Properties.StoreTokens(new[]
                            {
                                new AuthenticationToken { Name = "access_token", Value = token }
                            });
                        }

                        tokenValidatedContext.Success();
                        return tokenValidatedContext.Result;
                    }
                }

                if (validationFailures != null)
                {
                    var authenticationFailedContext = new AuthenticationFailedContext(Context, Scheme, Options)
                    {
                        Exception = (validationFailures.Count == 1) ? validationFailures[0] : new AggregateException(validationFailures)
                    };

                    await Events.AuthenticationFailed(authenticationFailedContext);
                    if (authenticationFailedContext.Result != null)
                    {
                        return authenticationFailedContext.Result;
                    }

                    return AuthenticateResult.Fail(authenticationFailedContext.Exception);
                }

                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No SecurityTokenValidator available for token: " + token ?? "[null]");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO: and here
                // Logger.ErrorProcessingMessage(ex);

                var authenticationFailedContext = new AuthenticationFailedContext(Context, Scheme, Options)
                {
                    Exception = ex
                };

                await Events.AuthenticationFailed(authenticationFailedContext);
                if (authenticationFailedContext.Result != null)
                {
                    return authenticationFailedContext.Result;
                }

                throw;
            }
        }

        protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
        {
            return base.HandleChallengeAsync(properties);
        }

        protected override Task HandleForbiddenAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
        {
            return base.HandleForbiddenAsync(properties);
        }
    }
```

I also implemented the extension for register it.

```cs
public static class AuthExtensions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddJwtBearerForExternalAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, Action<JwtBearerOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions>());
            return builder.AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomHandler>(authenticationScheme, null, configureOptions);
        }
    }
```

There are two scenarios, if I register the AuthenticationHandler as the following, it does not reach HandleAuthenticateAsync,

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearerForExternalAuth(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, _ => { });
```

But if I do register by setting default values explicitly, an exception is thrown,

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options => 
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearerForExternalAuth(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, _ => { });
```

The thrown exception is `InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.`

Then I add the default challenge schema to the options,

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options => 
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearerForExternalAuth(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, _ => { });
```

And it does not reach the **HandleAuthenticateAsync** again, it goes directly to **HandleChallengeAsync**.

My question is, Why I can't reach **HandleAuthenticateAsync** without producing an exception? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,